Exposing Graphql introspection with Spring (Boot) Security
I have a pretty standard Spring Boot application that I just started with Spring Security using JWT. I've added in the spring boot start GraphQL support (which I've done on a non-secured app in the past) and it works fine. However, I'm struggling to find a solution on how to allow access to /graphiql that will work correctly since the call to instrospect the schema is to the /graphql route which I have locked down since that's the route that all my data calls are made on to the resolvers.
I've tried a couple of different filters and applied them to the security filter chain like so..
.addFilterBefore(new IntrospectionQueryFilter(), usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
public class IntrospectionQueryFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        // No initialization needed
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        final var method = httpRequest.getMethod();
        final var uri = httpRequest.getRequestURI();

        if (isIntrospectionQuery(httpRequest)) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            // Proceed to authentication
            httpResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    }

    private boolean isIntrospectionQuery(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        final var method = request.getMethod();
        final var uri = request.getRequestURI();
        if (uri.equals("/graphiql") || uri.equals("/favicon.ico")) {
            return true;
        }
        if ("POST".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod()) && "/graphql".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getRequestURI())) {
            BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
            StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                body.append(line);
            }
            return body.toString().contains("\"operationName\":\"IntrospectionQuery\"");
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // No resources to clean up
    }
}

But this doesn't seem to work. I can't find a way to customize the introspection call so that it's on a non-secured route other than /graphql.

Maybe you could use Field Validation Instrumentation.

If errors are returned during this process then the query execution is aborted and the errors will be in the query result.

Something like:
@Component
public class IntrospectionInstrumentation extends FieldValidationInstrumentation {

    public IntrospectionInstrumentation() {
        super(validationEnvironment -> {
            if (isIntrospection(validationEnvironment)) {
                return Collections.emptyList();
            }
            final var authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            final boolean isAuthorized = authentication.getAuthorities().stream().anyMatch(a -> a.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_ADMIN"));
            if (isAuthorized) {
                return Collections.emptyList();
            }
            final GraphQLError error = GraphQLError.newError()
                    .errorType(ErrorType.UNAUTHORIZED)
                    .message("Not authorized")
                    .build();
            return List.of(error);
        });
    }

    private static boolean isIntrospection(FieldValidationEnvironment env) {
        return env.getExecutionContext().getExecutionInput().getOperationName().equals("IntrospectionQuery");
    }
}


Ah, that's interesting. I'll give that a go and see how it works and report back.
